# Batch: Copy files, with same partial name, from subfolders to another one

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, subdirectory, xcopy

I want to copy files, who has a part of his name in common, from a known number of subfolders. I tried with this code:

```
@Echo Off
rem Check if the aFolder exists and delete it if it exists

IF EXIST "%~dp0\aFolder" (
     rd /s /q "%~dp0\aFolder"
)

rem Create a new aFolder
mkdir "%~dp0\aFolder"

rem Copy the files from the subfolders inside of bFolder to aFolder    
For /F "tokens=1" %%A in (%~dp0\subFoldersList.txt) do (
    For /F "tokens=1" %%B in (%~dp0\formatList.txt) do (
        pushd "%~dp0\bFolder\%%A"
        For %%C in (%%AcommonPart.%%B) do xcopy %%C "%~dp0\aFolder"
    )
)
```

The code use two txt files that contains different data. 
In subFoldersList.txt:

```
subFolder1
subFolder2
subFolder3
```

In formatList.txt:

```
xls
xlsx
xlsm
```

Checking the code the loop doesn't run never and I unknown why.

**Edit:**

The folders skeleton that I use is this:

```
rootFolder
|->aFolder
||-->subFolder1
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsx (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xls (for example)
||-->subFolder2
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsx (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xls (for example)
||-->subFolder3
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xls (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xlsx (for example)
|->bFolder
|->subFoldersList.txt
|->formatList.txt
|->Other Stuff
```

I want to obtain this result:

```
rootFolder
|->aFolder
||-->subFolder1
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsx (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xls (for example)
||-->subFolder2
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsx (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xls (for example)
||-->subFolder3
|||--->subFolder1commomPart.xls (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other1Part.xlsm (for example)
|||--->subFolder1other2Part.xlsx (for example)
|->bFolder
||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsx (for example)
||--->subFolder1commomPart.xlsm (for example)
||--->subFolder1commomPart.xls (for example)
|->subFoldersList.txt
|->formatList.txt
|->Other Stuff
```

Comment: **%~dp0** already has a trailing backslash, remove the ones you've added following it!

Comment: I think `For %%C in (%%AcommonPart.%%B) do xcopy %%C "%~dp0\aFolder"` should be changed to `For %%C in ("commonPart.%%B") do xcopy "%%~C" "%~dp0\aFolder\"`, because `pushd` already changed to sub-folder `%%A`; note also the improved quoting, the `~` in `%%~C` and the trailing backslash at the destination. You should also change `tokens=1` to `delims=`. Please show us some samples of file names...

Comment: You have to issue a `POPD` as well.

Comment: @Compo Thanks. I already use the backslash before and the codes run well.

Comment: @Tilan04, it was advice only, try addind a line `ECHO %~dp0` and you'll see that whilst your way may have worked for you before it is wrong. My answer below, which makes other changes also shows my advice in action.

Comment: @aschipfl With the %%~C the code go in a good way but doesn't reach the directory. I was working on it until I read the last advise from Compo that made works the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what you've provided thus far, maybe this is what you intended:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

REM Make sure script directory is current
IF /I NOT "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0" 2>NUL||EXIT/B

REM Make sure source files exist
FOR %%A IN ("subFoldersList.txt" "formatList.txt") DO IF NOT EXIST %%A EXIT/B

REM Delete aFolder if it exists
IF EXIST "aFolder\" RD/S/Q "aFolder"

REM Create aFolder
MD "aFolder"

REM Copy the files from the subfolders inside of bFolder to aFolder    
FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%A IN ("subFoldersList.txt") DO (
    IF EXIST "bFolder\%%A\" (PUSHD "bFolder\%%A"
        FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%B IN ("%~dp0formatList.txt") DO (
            IF EXIST "commonPart.%%B" (
                IF NOT EXIST "%~dp0aFolder\commonPart.%%B" (
                    COPY "commonPart.%%B" "%~dp0aFolder")))
        POPD))
```

Comment: The code isn't working. I tried to check with a  pause after the input of a command but didn't run the first for-loop.

Comment: There are simple things to do in order to debug or provide feedback on someones code, "the code isn't working" isn't really sufficient information for me to help. If it doesn't get to the first loop then it's likely at least one of the txt files doesn't exist along side the script.

Comment: Yes... It was it. I renamed the files name and one letter was missing. lol  Thanks for your help.